# Facebook oauth javascript redirect resulting in endless loop

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication

I want to redirect users to the oauth page if they have removed any of the permissions my app requires.

For some reason the below code results in an endless loop when I try to redirect from the FB.api callback function. Any ideas how I can fix this?

```
var perms           = ['publish_actions', 'email', 'user_birthday', 'user_location'],
    permsString     = perms.join(','),
    permissionsUrl  = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth';
    permissionsUrl  += '?client_id=' + config.facebook.appId;
    permissionsUrl  += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURI(canvasUrl);
    permissionsUrl  += '&scope=' + permsString;

    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {

        if (response.status === 'connected') {

            FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response) {

                // using underscore here...
                var keys = _.keys(response.data[0]),
                    diff = _.difference(perms, keys);

                // send the user through the auth again if they've removed any of the perms we need
                if (diff.length) {

                    window.location.href = permissionsUrl; // results in an endless redirect loop
                    // window.location.href = 'http://randomwebsite.com'; // does redirect successfully!!!!
                }
            });
        }

    }, true);
```

Comment: through trial and error I found that wrapping the redirect in a named function outside of the callback and then invoking this in the callback seemed to do the trick

Comment: @techijacker I am having similar issues.. can you give some examples on how you overcome this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I did this but from memory I solved it with something like this:

```
var redirectMe = function (link) {
  window.location.href = link;
};

FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response) {
            if (true) {
                redirectMe('http://www.browsehappy.com');
            }
        });
    }
}, true);
```